# max-height nested not working

Tags: html, css

I am applying max-height to nested divs? but it is not working as expected root element working is perfect but child height not applying?

```
<div style="max-height: calc( 33% - 10px);">
  <div style="height:30px;"></div>
  <div style="max-height: calc( 100% - 30px);">
    //height not applying
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In which browser are you testing ?

Comment: its chrome latest version

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, percentage heights are calculated from the *explicitely specified* `height` of the parent element, not its actual height. If `height` is not set, it is `auto`, which can't be used for percentage. Only Opera 12- (Presto) calculates percantage `min-height` from the specified `min-height` directly.

Assuming you don't care about old browsers (since you use such modern features like `calc()`), I'd suggest to try Flexbox for this layout.